# Difference between Windows 8 Store Apps And Windows Phone Apps

Tags: windows-8, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml, portable-class-library

I know this seems basic, but I have spent hours looking at docs and videos and cant seem to find the answer. Sorry if I'm being a doof.

Is there a difference between Windows 8 App Store Development and Windows 8 Phone Development? I am not sure if I need to test on both UI's?

J

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you have used the MVVM pattern (like you should) then you likely have separated your XAML and View Models, Models into separate projects. As a result, your non-XAML projects will port over to your Windows Phone 8 app almost 99%. There will be some subtle differences, but not many.

From the perspective of your XAML (or your UI) they simply have to be different because they are different form factors and Windows 8 controls (like AppBar) aren't in Windows Phone 8 and some Windows Phone 8 controls (like Panorama) aren't in Windows 8. As a result, you can't just take your W8 XAML and jam it into WP8 - it would possibly not work and certainly look bad.

Having said that, reusing the same strategies and design you implemented in W8 SnapView is probably a good idea - or at least a good start. But remember, we're talking UI here. Meanwhile, your WinRT-based code is almost completely portable.

Comment: Know i shouldn't use comments for thank you's... but thank you for this very well considered and useful answer.

Comment: good said Jerry Nixon - MSFT. i had wasted  lot of time for searching this thing. Now you made it simple and clear

Comment: I am happy to report that this answer will change when Windows Phone 8.1 comes along. The XAML implementation is far more portable than it is in Windows Phone 8.0.

Answer (score 15):

All these days I was thinking that Microsoft made Windows 8 as universal operating system for the various device like smart phone, tablet, surface tablet, desktop.

My assumption went wrong.

Windows RT runs on tablet  and Windows 8 Pro runs on desk top, (windows RT and Windows 8 pro are different version of windows 8 OS).

Window Phone 8 OS is the second generation mobile operating system from Microsoft which runs under the mobile hardware.

Windows has got two different stores for Windows phone 8 App and Windows store app.

I started developing windows store app thinking that it will run on windows 8 phone. I really disappointed.

In case of android and IOS phone and tab share the same OS and single app run on both tab and phone. I am not sure why does Microsoft did not developed window 8 OS like that. I understand that internally windows phone 8 uses windows 8 kernel but still it is different operating system.

To Develop windows phone 8 app we have to use windows phone 8 sdk. Where as for the windows 8 store app we just use visual studio and store app framework.
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: is it true even now in 2016?
I was thinking that by making windows store app, I could just run it on windows phone.

Answer (score 1):

They will have to be entirely separate applications.  While the WinRT and WP8 apis will be very similar in many respects, they are not totally compatible and the screen resolutions are not the same.